# Trying to free an array of character array in C result in double free or corruption

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am working on a project in which I have to create an array of string (char *), however, when I try to free the array of array, "double free or corruption" is given and I couldn't figure out the problem.

The code extraction here is a simplified version, it may seem meaningless but it illustrates the problem I am facing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **cptr;
    int i;

    cptr = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        cptr[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(char));
        cptr[i][0] = (char)i;
    }
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        free(cptr[i]);
    }
    free(cptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `256*sizeof(char *)` gets you 256 pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cptr = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
```

Above line is wrong. Even if you compute number of bytes allocated above, it is 256 bytes. If size of pointer is 4 bytes on your machine, it would be enough for 64 pointers. Instead you need 256 pointers. Use

```
cptr = malloc(256 * sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: Everything make sense now. On the other hand, when I try to debug the program, I try `for (i=0; i<256; i++) { printf("%d",i); free(cptr[i]); }` and the terminal shows 0 then shows the error. However, the cptr should have enough space for some pointers (say a pointer is 4 bytes, it will at least have space for 64 pointers). But it seems that freeing the first pointer already gave the problem. Is there particular reason to explain this? Thank you.

Comment: @user3259983 you already consumed more bytes than you had, using c[i]=calloc.., which triggers undefined behavior, which means [anything](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c) can happen. c[i] consumes four bytes.

Comment: It's semi-idiomatic to use the size of a pointed-to element in the computation (i.e. `cptr = malloc(256 * sizeof *cptr)`) to avoid errors like this.  Missing out the `*` is of course equally possible, but if you're used to the idiom, it should at least cause a raised eyebrow.